# Add time values in minutes and display in hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 fields. The first field is where users enters the start time (hours and minutes). The second field is where users enter the time in minutes.

Now I want to add the two fields and display the result in the third field (in hours and minutes).

I'm trying to do this but have had no success yet. Any pointers?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Time 1</h3>
      <input type="text" name="t1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Time 2</h3>
      <input type="text" name="t2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Time 3</h3>
      <input type="text" name="t3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your current JS code to the question so we can help you debug it.

Comment: And don't use an `<input>` for output. You can just set `textContent` of a `<p>` or `<span>`.